# Rewrite vs Redirect from ?p={ID}

Tags: url-rewriting, redirect, htaccess

WordPress does a 301 from `http://example.com/?p=100` to `http://example.com/post-title/`, but I thought a URL rewrite was different from a redirect and therefore this wouldn't result in a 301.

Can anyone clarify?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A *rewrite* enables `http://example.com/post-title/` to translate internally to the proper query vars to load the requested post. The shortlink does a 301 *redirect* to the pretty URL because it should not be possible to access the same content from more than one URI. This is so a search engine won't index the same post under two URIs.